# portaudio ALSA Pulse Jack Raspian

Tags: alsa, portaudio, jack, pulse

I have a RPI 4 running in Raspian (Dec 2020) and they use Pulse audio on top of ALSA.
The ARM portaudio lib calls functions in the Jack audio lib so if I link that lib
with the portaudio lib in a C program,  the program compiles and links error free but freezes immediately after start.
A Python program that uses portaudio through the pyaudio lib works (also on RPI 4).

I have some real understanding problems about these libs.
C code  --> Portaudio lib --> Jack audio.lib --> ALSA
and  Python code --> pyaudio lib  --> Portaudio lib --> Pulse audio.lib --> ALSA
or is it possible that portaudio can call ALSA directly and how to do that?

The portaudio.com website seems to be down (for good or just temporary?)

Comment: What do you mean by or good or just temporary?

Comment: Well, since weeks www.portaudio.com does  not reply at all. So did they close the page for ever or do they have temporary problems?

Comment: Okay makes sense. It looks like there are temporary problems.